# adding input value in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am facing problem in java-script problem as 
I have to collect all subrole from screen whenever user focus out from input field.this is my code

```
var subrole_id = [];
$("ul :input[class^='sub']").live('focusout', function() {
var get_id = $(this).attr('class').split("_");
        var ids = get_id[2];
        var ids_index = get_id[3];
subrole_id[ids][ids_index] = this.value;
});
```

but this is giving error

```
TypeError: subrole_id[ids] is undefined
subrole_id[ids][ids_index] = this.value;
```

Actually I want to collect value of subrole input field and add them in array with index `ids` one by one and before adding that value in array I have to check whether that present value is present in array or not if yes then do not add and give error.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a true multidimensional array in javascript, just an array of array, so you have to create the subArray:

```
subrole_id[ids]=subrole_id[ids]||[];
subrole_id[ids][ids_index] = this.value;
```